# How to get edges and normal map from 3D model?

Tags: rendering, edges, normal-map

I want to extract edges and normal maps from the 3d model using freestyle.
However, my rendered normal map looks like this[image]

But it should look like this.
[image]

there are two problems, there's no blue channel in the rendered normal map. And there is a shaded area which is black even lamp exists there.

I think I should render matcap in shading properties, but I have no idea how to render like matcap.[image]

Comment: The thing you want is called *world normal map* (global normal map), and depends on how the normal vector is stored in map, the color can be black in certain case. You should specify your question a little bit more on what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ref: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/blender_render/textures/properties/influence/bump_normal.html#bump-normal-maps

> Normal maps in Blender store a normal as follows:
>
> - Red maps from (0 - 255) to X (-1.0 - 1.0)
> - Green maps from (0 - 255) to Y (-1.0 - 1.0)
> - Blue maps from (0 - 255) to Z (0.0 - 1.0)
>
> Since normals all point towards a viewer, negative Z values are not stored (they would be invisible anyway). In Blender we store a full blue range, although some other implementations also map blue colors (128 - 255) to (0.0 - 1.0). The latter convention is used in “Doom 3” for example.

If you want to achieve the default Blender normal map definition *(z start from 0.0 instead of -1.0)*. You need to defined what will happen if `-1 < z < 0`

Below is two examples for how to calculate it by node editor:

[image: Genaral]

[image: World normal setting]

Is the first one you are asking for?